# Throw an error with number line if a json file contains a dictionary with duplicate keys

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to throw an error if a json file contains a dictionary with duplicate keys.
My question is: How to add the line number in json to the error? The json can contain comments or empty lines. I can count lines but the question if there is any better solution ?

This is the code:

```
import json
def dict_raise_on_duplicates(ordered_pairs):
    """Reject duplicate keys."""
    d = {}
    for k, v in ordered_pairs:
        if k in d:
           raise ValueError("duplicate key: %r" % (k,))
        else:
           d[k] = v
    return d
```

file_content: any string or file

```
   {
        "fruit": "Apple",
        "size": "Large",
        "size": "Red"
       }
```

and main

```
  def main():
      try:
          data = json.loads(file_content, object_pairs_hook=dict_raise_on_duplicates)
      except ValueError as e:
          print("Error: the JSON has syntax error: " + str(e))
          exit(1)
```

Comment: `file_content` is _already_ a dictionary, and you haven't shown us `object_pairs` at all.  This code can't possibly work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I think checking the length of your key array maybe the best way. You can also use a set. So,

```
d = set(ordered_pairs)
if len(d) < len(ordered_pairs):
    raise ValueError("")
```

For finding out the line of the data that throws exception -

```
import json
def dict_raise_on_duplicates(ordered_pairs):
    """Reject duplicate keys."""
    d = {}
    count = 0
    for k, v in ordered_pairs:
        if k in d:
           raise ValueError(f'Error from data line: {count}')
        else:
           d[k] = v
           count += 1
    return d
```

Comment: What does contain "ordered_pairs" ? I gave as an example only one dictionary but it can list, dictionary and etc... @SW jeong

Comment: @Alex if it is a dict, then you should treat that as a dict so set(ordered_pairs.keys()), etc. But dict would not allow duplicate keys anyways. If it is a list, create another list with the first element of all elements.

Comment: I didn't understand. Do you send me a doc page ? @SW Jeong

Comment: And my question about line number. No how to find a duplicate key @SW Jeong

Comment: @Alex A set is a data structure that does not allow duplicates. Therefore, when you construct a set object, you will be left with keys without duplicates - thus its length being the length you can use to see if there exist duplicates in other objects.

Comment: But it's not my question. My question is how to print the line number where is an error. @SW Jeong

Comment: I see, if you want to find the specific item that does not meet your condition, you have to loop through everything - like you are doing right now. It really depends on which data structure you are using, but the most general solution to this would be to maintain a counter that increments while you have not reached your error condition. Look at my edit.